# Create PDFs of all Powerpoint files in a folder

Tags: vba, pdf, pdf-generation, powerpoint

I have a number of Powerpoint files in a folder (around 10 or so) and am looking to create VBA in Powerpoint that will PDF all of them.  What I have appears to work, but it PDFs most of the files but not all of them.  No idea why - the ppts it misses each time will vary.

I'm running the below 'OpenPPts' which is calling the the sub 'CreatePdfs'.  Calling the CreatePdfs as a separate sub is ideal for me as I can change this to complete other tasks.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Sub OpenPpts()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolderName As String
    Dim PP As Presentation
    
    Dim oSld As Slide
 
  On Error Resume Next

    
  strFolderName = "C:\my ppt files\"

  strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.pptx")
    
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
       Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)
 
        'enter the vba to call below

Call CreatePdf
        
         PP.Save
        PP.Close
       
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub




Sub CreatePdf()


'saves opens PPT as PDF in the same folder and applies same name.

    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint

End Sub
```

Comment: There's an extra \ in your path

Comment: Per @TimWilliams comment:  Change 
strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.pptx") to strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "*.pptx")  
Likewise, change Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName) to Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName &  strFileName)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I've made these corrections and all seem to be working well - many thanks.  I ran into more problems with the PDFs occasionally not appearing.  It seems this was at least in part down to the location being saved onto onedrive.  As soon as I use a folder not backup on onedrive, there are no problems.

Comment: @OwenJohnson Glad it helped (and credit to Tim Williams for pointing out the problem first). Problems when automating files on OneDrive is not unusual, in my experience. Best to do everything locally, then save to OneDrive afterward for distribution if needed.